# did not receive a response from an authoritative server

Tags: java, docx4j

I'm using docx4j-3.3.1 library and running this project  Here's [a link](https://github.com/plutext/PDF-Converter-Java/blob/master/src/sample/java/Sample.java)  but it show me error like this

```
Looks like your endpoint URL 'http://converter-eval.plutext.com:80/v1/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/convert' is wrong
Something went wrong...
main.java.com.plutext.converter.ConversionException: This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server
    at main.java.com.plutext.converter.ConverterHttp.execute(ConverterHttp.java:194)
    at main.java.com.plutext.converter.ConverterHttp.convert(ConverterHttp.java:76)
    at sample.java.Sample.main(Sample.java:66)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1276)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:111)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
    at main.java.com.plutext.converter.ConverterHttp.execute(ConverterHttp.java:184)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As it says:

```
    java.net.UnknownHostException: This is usually a temporary error during
    hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a 
    response from an authoritative server
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
```

Comment: but we are getting this error frequently, is there any option to increase the time out to avoid such error always?